# Codeigniter's $uri and $perPage in db query

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have the following function in my model to fetch some data from database and I am using codeigniter's default pagination class and for that I have $perPage and $uri in the following code.

```
function payment_due($month,$year,$fee_type,$perPage,$uri ) { 

$getData = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT studentid,studentname FROM
 student  WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT * FROM studentpayment1 JOIN studentpayment2 
                      ON studentpayment1.paymentid=studentpayment2.pid
WHERE fee_month='$month' AND fee_type='$fee_type' 
 AND fee_year='$year' AND student.studentid=studentpayment1.studentid )
 " );


        if($getData->num_rows() > 0)
        return $getData->result_array();
        else
        return null;
        }
```

Usually when I fetch data from a table I use  $perPage and $uri like this->

```
$getData = $this->db->get('', $perPage, $uri);
```

Now my question is would you please kindly tell me where should I use the $perPage and $uri in the above function?

Thanks in Advance :)

If I use $perPage, $uri at the end of my db query I get the following error:

```
  A Database Error Occurred
 Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL  server version for the right syntax to
use near '15' at line 3

 SELECT DISTINCT studentid,studentname FROM student WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT * FROM   studentpayment1 JOIN studentpayment2
  ON  studentpayment1.paymentid=studentpayment2.pid WHERE 
 fee_month='February' AND fee_type='Monthly Fee' AND fee_year='2012'
  AND student.studentid=studentpayment1.studentid ) LIMIT ,15

  Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\utc\system\database\DB_driver.php
```

Line Number: 330
`

Comment: when doing pagination you need number of rows to show and how many at the end of your sql. E.g. get start at record 5, getting 10 records; SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 1 LIMIT 5, 10

Answer (score 0):

In [user_guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select) you can see the code sample for `$this->db->get()` and what is produced:

> The second and third parameters enable you to set a limit and offset
>   clause:

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable', 10, 20);

// Produces: SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 20, 10 (in MySQL. Other databases have slightly different syntax)
```

So basically you need to set `LIMIT` in your query by adding at the end of it something like that:

```
LIMIT $uri,$perPage
```

Comment: Thanks Kokers .If I use Limit $uri,$Perpage at the end of my querry I get this->  Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '15' at line 3

Comment: I am using this $config['per_page']=15,$this->uri->segment(3)

Comment: also, check if there is `,` between `$uri` and `$perPage`. this: `LIMIT 5,15` is ok, this `LIMIT 5 15` is not ok.

Comment: Please check the updated post above. Please don't spend your valuable time on it if you think its complicated. :) thanks

Comment: It's not so complicated ;o) it's simple. You can see that `$this->uri->segment(3)` is empty. So you get `LIMIT ,15` I supose it's because it's first page where there isn't anything set in 3 segment. So if you want use `$this->uri->segment()` to determine offset check if it's empty and if it is set to 0. or use it like that `(int)$this->uri->segment(3)` so if it will be empty the int will change null to 0 - it should be a number anyway.